# Is there a decision tree impurity metric based on maximum of probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cart

I'm trying to understand impurity metrics in decision tree learning, in particular the Gini impurity. Questioning one of the assumptions of Gini impurity has led me to another impurity measure which makes much more sense to me but I can't find much information about it online.

Say we have a classification problem with $ K $ classes. To decide which attribute to split on, we pretend we've already done the split and take a weighted sum of the impurity measure across the child nodes. We repeat this for each attribute and pick the attribute that minimises the weighted sum.

Assume the relative frequencies of the classes at a child node are $ p_1, \dots, p_K $. The Gini impurity for the child node is then $ 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{K} p_i^2 $. The way I rationalise this is that if we randomly assign a class to the child node according to the probability distribution, then the Gini coefficient is the probability that a new, random example at that node is misclassified.

But why would we assign the class of the node randomly? Surely the best choice would be to assign the class with the highest relative frequency at that node. Then the probability that a new, random example is misclassified is $ 1 - \max_{i=1}^{K} p_i $. This gives a new type of impurity.

I have come across something called Tsallis entropy, which has a parameter $ q $. In the limit $ q \rightarrow 1 $, Tsallis entropy converges to Shannon entropy. For $ q = 2 $, it's equal to Gini impurity. The new impurity defined above relates to the limit $ q \rightarrow \infty $.

Is there any "obvious" theoretical reason why this maximum-based impurity is worse than the mainstream ones of Shannon entropy and Gini impurity? Or is it just that the other ones were invented first and perform well in practice, so there was no need to look for anything else?